# How to set style to a div that selected by :last-child

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to **set a style for the header** shown in below pug template:

```
.section1
  .dropdown-card
  .dropdown-card
  .dropdown-card
    .header
```

I'm able to select last `dropdown-card` class in the section1 using `:last-child` pseudo-class. Like this:

```
  .dropdown-card:last-child{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
  }
```

But, I'm not able to select `.header` which is inside of `.dropdown-card` class. These methods not working:

```
.dropdown-card:last-child .header {}
.dropdown-card:last-child > .header {}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Try  `.dropdown-card > .header {}`

Comment: @MinalChauhan nope. Not working.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: If you actually do have the `.header` nested in the `.dropdown-card` and one of your cards actually matches `.dropdown-card:last-child` then `.dropdown-card:last-child .header` will select your header. Better check if your runtime nesting is what you expect it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

If the header class is inside the `.dropdown-card` class then remove `:last-child` from your code -

```css
.dropdown-card .header {}
```

Comment: Tried. Not working.

Comment: Plz show the full code, so that I'll be able to help u more

Answer (score 0):

That `.dropdown-card:last-child .header` work like:

```css
.dropdown-card:last-child .header {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="section1">
  <div class="dropdown-card">
    <p>
      content
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-card">
    <p>
      content
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-card">
    <div class="header">
      <p>
        content
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

My suspect you try to use .header with pure tag header, if yes just use `.dropdown-card:last-child header`, same code without "point", because is not a class.

```css
.dropdown-card:last-child header {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="section1">
  <div class="dropdown-card">
    <p>
      content
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-card">
    <p>
      content
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-card">
    <header>
      <p>
        content
      </p>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I'm sure that it is a class with **point**.

Comment: @anileates as you can see from my first example work.